# Create a simple countdown screen

Tags: objective-c, counter, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar based application where the first screen should show a countdown to a special event.

Most of the code examples I've seen both on Stack Overflow and through googling, seems to implement the counter in the viewDidLoad method, which seems to the counter run when switching to another view controller.

What is the correct implementation of the counter mechanism?

My current code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _targetDateString = @"09-07-2014";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

    _targetDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    _targetDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:_targetDateString];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *componentsDaysDiff = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now toDate:_targetDate options:0];

    if (componentsDaysDiff.day > 0)
    {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

-(void)updateCountdown
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:_targetDateString];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *componentsHours = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    NSDateComponents *componentMint = [calendar components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    NSDateComponents *componentSec = [calendar components:NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *componentsDayDiff = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                               fromDate:now
                                                                 toDate:dateFromString
                                                                options:0];

    NSLog(@"days: %02d, %02d hours, %02d minutes and %02d seconds", componentsDayDiff.day, componentsHours.hour, componentMint.minute, componentSec.second);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

im not sure if i fully understand what you want the timer to do, but if you want the timer to start and stop only when looking at a particular view, you will want to start the timer in `- (void) viewDidAppear` by calling `[timer fire]` and stop it in `- (void) viewWillDisappear` by calling `[timer invalidate]`